# VS Code git extension: Merge Conflict after Synchronizing Changes in untouched files

Tags: git

The following happened to me: I was developing something for a long time on the master branch, everything was going well. A different developer was developing on an older branch and after several months I tried pulling these changes. I had not changed a lot on this branch in a long time.

When pulling the VS Code git extension told me there are 65 commits to pull, 0 to push. Several merge conflicts came up in 15 different files (and lots of them in each file). The weird thing is that it was mostly in files I had never touched in my life.

Two questions:

1. How can a merge conflict come up if I'm not pushing anything?
2. Why do I have to resolve a merge conflict in a file that I have never touched/seen before? Even if there were merge conflicts between other developers codes, when they merged their branches git should have forced them to resolve these conflicts right?

Comment: "I tried pulling these changes" is meaningless. Please show the actual conversation: what you said and what Git said. Do a git status and show us that too.

Comment: Im using the VS Code git extension but I‘ll revise the question

Comment: "How can a merge conflict come up if I'm not pushing anything?" Pull is a merge. Therefore there can be a merge conflict.

Comment: I‘m really confused. I simply entered git pull into the console and it pulled without merge conflicts. Seems like a problem with the VS Code extension?

Comment: I am very willing to explain Git phenomena to you but I need specifics of those phenomena, as I have already requested.

Answer (score -1):

There seemed to be a problem with the git extension of VS Code. The solution was to pull the changes via the console.

1. `git merge —abort` to remove all merge conflicts from code
2. `git pull` to simply pull all the changes

Like this no merge conflicts came up anymore.

Comment: I don't find this a satisfactory explanation. You still have not told us clearly what you did and what happened as a result. I don't believe in this "blame the tools" dismissal of things.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I'm sorry I don't know how to do that. I pressed the "Synchronize Changes" Button in the VS Code git extension which showed me that there are 65 commits to pull and 0 to push. Then VS Code told me that there are merge conflicts. Since they are resolved now and the code is merged already I am unable to reproduce this phenomena so I can't show you any further console outputs.

Comment: Then I recommend deleting the question, as there seems to be no way to ascertain what the question even is.

Comment: I would agree but maybe someone else will have the same problem in the future? I edited the question a little so that it fits better to the problem